# How can I add an onchange event from a component calling another component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using this lines in my lightning component:

```
<fieldset id="someID" onchange="{!c.someJSFunction}">
<c:inputlookup type="{!sometype}" value="{!somevalue}" className="slds-input"/> 
<lightning:input aura:id="anotherId" name="anotherAccId" value="{!somevalue}" />
</fieldset>
```

as you can see I am using another component inside the fieldset. What I wanted to do is that every time the inputlookup changes, it will also perform the someJSFunction.

this is the sample content of the someJSFunction:

```
var someAccId = component.find("anotherId").get("v.value");
console.log('someAccId '+someAccId );
```

but it didn't work. How can I get the method to be called every time there is a change from the component inputlookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `c:inputlookup`, you can [register a component event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_fire.htm) called `myChangeEvent`, which you fire anytime there's a change happening in your `c:inputlookup` component.

Then you can detect changes within the parent component inline with your other inputLookup attributes like this:

`<c:inputlookup type="{!sometype}" value="{!somevalue}" className="slds-input" myChangeEvent="{! c.handleInputLookupChanges }"/>`

Then the parent's JS controller can handle the changes in the `handleInputLookupChanges` controller method however you please.  Look into `event.getParams()` to see how to handle incoming changes.